# NuxtJS 2 modules have a bad effect on pwa app performance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, memory-leaks, nuxt.js, google-tag-manager

I have a pwa app created with NuxtJS version 2. It has a good lighthouse value and app works fine. But when I add "@nuxtjs/device" or "@nuxtjs/gtm" modules and setup them in modules section in nuxt.config.js app start to work bad. It happens evcen without settings for this modules.

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6",
    "@nuxtjs/device": "2.1.0",
    "@nuxtjs/gtm": "^2.4.0",
    "@nuxtjs/pwa": "^3.3.5",
    "core-js": "^3.25.3",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
    "vue": "^2.7.10",
    "vue-server-renderer": "^2.7.10",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.10"
  },
```

nuxt.config.js

```
modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/pwa
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
    '@nuxtjs/device',
    '@nuxtjs/gtm',
  ]
```

UPDATE:
This article https://www.voorhoede.nl/en/blog/your-website-probably-has-a-memory-leak/ is describe the problem

Comment: What does "the app starts to work bad" mean? It's hard to help without specifying the problem.

Comment: @Kapcash sorry for answer. I check lighthose report, it is about 90, but after module installation it becames 31